# How to cancel a pending .NET 3.5 Installation on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: installation, .net-framework, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried to install a HP printer driver package that obviously needed .NET 3.5. The installation failed for some reason and I canceled it. Now, on login of all users, the system tries to finish the .NET installation, but fails.
The error dialog says "The following feature could not be installed: .NET Framework 3.5 (contains .NET 2.0 and 3.0)."

Apparently this is a conflict between System-control "Windows Features" and the Server Manager (I am not sure about the English names as I am running a German version).

I now simply want to get rid of the error message and cancel the installation completely. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your question.  I have a little experience about windows server 2012-r2 but I had an experience regarding  .NET issue .  So my suggestion is that , log in to the server:

1. Then in the windows menu search for "`gpedit`" ,
2. click "Group Policy editor", then try finding "`Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates-->System`" .
3. After clicking "System" folder see the settings files on right side window.
4. Look for "`Specify Settings for Optional Component installation and component repair`" by scrolling down , double click on it .
5. In the new window , enable the feature .
6. Then look for "`Contact windows update directly to download repair content instead of Windows Server Update Service(WSUS)`". Enable it .
7. Then Apply-->Ok.
8. Now open command prompt as admin . Type "`gpupdate /force`"
9. Now go to Control Panel-->Programs-->Programs and Features page and click "Turn Windows features on or off" when the feature window pops up , select .NET Framework 3.5 and press ok.
10. In the new window , click "Download files from Windows Update" . After finishing Installation don't forget to restart your server.

I hope this will help you up setting .NET 3.5 on your server.

Comment: Danke :) Now the installation went through and I got rid of that dialog. Should I revert the update service setting? Will it have other impacts?